# Asymptotic behavior of integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-xt}}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt$ as $x \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I wish to prove that:

$$ \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-xt}}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt \sim - \ln x \quad  \mathrm{as} \quad x \to 0^+$$

using the fact that:

$$ f \underset{b}{\sim} g \Rightarrow \int_a^x f \underset{x \to b}{\sim} \int_a^x g$$

if $\int_a^x g \to \infty$ as $x \to b$ and $f$ and $g$ are integrable on every interval $[a,c]$ with $c < b$.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\left.\int_{1}^{\infty}{\expo{-xt} \over \root{1 + t^{2}}}\,\dd t\,
\right\vert_{\ x\ >\ 0} =
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\expo{-xt} \over t}\,\dd t +
\int_{1}^{\infty}\expo{-xt}\pars{{1 \over \root{1 + t^{2}}} - {1 \over t}}
\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
x\int_{1}^{\infty}\ln\pars{t}\expo{-xt}\,\dd t
-
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\expo{-xt} \over t\root{1 + t^{2}}\pars{\root{1 + t^{2}} + t}}
\,\dd t
\\[1cm] & =
-\ln\pars{x}\expo{-x}
\\[5mm] & + \int_{x}^{\infty}\ln\pars{t}\expo{-t}\,\dd t + \int_{1}^{\infty}\ln\pars{t}\expo{-t}\,\dd t -
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\expo{-xt} \over t\root{1 + t^{2}}\pars{\root{1 + t^{2}} + t}}
\,\dd t
\end{align}
The 'remaining' integrals are *finite* as $\ds{x \to 0^{+}}$ such that
$$\bbx{\ds{%
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\expo{-xt} \over \root{1 + t^{2}}}\,\dd t \sim -\ln\pars{x}
\quad\mbox{as}\ x \to 0^{+}}}
$$

Comment: I'm not sure about the integration of the term $x\int_{1}^{\infty}\ln(t)e^{-xt}\, dt$.

Isn't it:

$$ x\int_{1}^{\infty}\ln(t)e^{-xt}\, dt = \int_{x}^{\infty}\ln(\frac{v}{x})e^{-v}\, dv \quad\mathrm{by \ doing} \; v= xt $$

$$ = -\ln(x)\int_x^\infty e^{-v}dv + \int_x^\infty \ln(v) e^{-v}dv$$

$$ = -\ln(x) e^{-x} + \int_x^\infty \ln(v) e^{-v}dv \quad \sim - \ln(x) \quad \mathrm{as} \; x \to 0^+ $$

Comment: @omardrwch You're right. I just fixed it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You may prove that
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-xt}}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,dt}{-\log x}=1 \tag{1}$$
by proving that:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-xt}}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,dt}{-1/x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{xt e^{-xt}}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,dt = 1.\tag{2} $$
The last integral equals:
$$ \int_{x}^{+\infty}\frac{t}{\sqrt{x^2+t^2}}\cdot e^{-t}\,dt\tag{3}$$
hence $(2)$ (then $(1)$) follows from the dominated convergence theorem.